# Kolmogorov forward equation with Mixed Dirichlet Neumann problem

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve symbolically the Kolmogorov forward equation for the transition probability p(x,y,t), viz,

```
pde = (1/2)*s*D[p[x, y, t], {y, 2}] - b*D[p[x, y, t], y] - D[p[x, y, t], t] == 0
```

where s>0 and b<0. The initial condition is
p[x,y,0]=DiracDelta[x-y]
The Dirichlet condition is
p[x,h,t]==0
where h is another numerical parameter.
I wrote the Neumann condition (that the partial of p relative to y at y=0 is 0) as follows:
D[p[x,y,t],y]=NeumannValue[0, y <= 0]
But I am having difficulties putting it altogether in the DSolve:

```
sol = DSolve[{pde, p[x,y, 0] == DiracDelta[x - y], 
   DirichletCondition[p[x,h, t] == 0, True], 
   D[p[x,y, t], y] == NeumannValue[0, y <= 0]}, p[x,y, t], {x,y, t}]
```

Apparently this is syntaxally accepted, but it only transcribes the instruction is plain math  notation and does not proceed to the solution. I tried to simplify as much as possible (remove the variable x, replacing s, b, and h by numerical values... but to no avail.) Any idea what I am doing wrong... Thanks for the help!

Comment: DSolve cannot solve your equation, I believe.  Not all pde's can be solved in principle, and `DSolve` sometimes fails to solve problems for which solutions are known.  When that happens, `DSolve` returns unevaluated.

Comment: @bbgodfrey can NDsolve be used for this problem?

Comment: Yes, it can, although you will need to specify boundary conditions and provide the range over which the integration is to be performed.  Also, it cannot handle delta functions.  Also, I would expect that the PDE can be solved by Fourier-expanding it.

Comment: The usage of `DirichletCondition` and `NeumannValue` is wrong, but correcting this isn't enough to resolve the problem. Can you add a bit more background info for the problem?

Comment: I need to solve the following PDE
pde = (1/2)*s*D[p[x, y, t], {y, 2}] - b*D[p[x, y, t], y] - D[p[x, y, t], t] == 0
over the interval (0,h), where h>0, subject to the Dirichlet condition that p(x,y,t) vanishes at y=h and the Neumann condition that the partial derivative of p(x,y,t) relative to y vanishes at y=0. Ideally, the initial condition p(x,y,0) is a Dirac delta at y=x, but a Gauss distribution for y centered at x would suffice. The PDE is the Kolmogorov forward equation for an Ito process reflecting at y=0 and "absorbed" at y=h.